# How can I create a product customization page where the user can customize in 3D

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x

I want to add a page to my website where the user will be able to see, in 3D, the product they will be personalizing.

Comment: Here are some questions: What have you tried? What website are you making? Where are your codes? What are your attempts? What research have you done? Why is there a python tag? Can you add more information and more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What product do they personalize? What user interface controls do you expose to the consumer? Do you have staff for pre-production?

- A poster, shirt or flat product -- use css or a dynamic texture https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_canvas
- A 3d print or virtual sculpt -- find some voxel composer
- A toy -- https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ldraw
- A kitchen-sink approach -- pre-render images as sprites (remember Rare?) and send the form to the "backend"... which can be a python script or some guy you hate. Tell the consumer they will get a response in 24h. Trust me, that's what enterprise software is all about. Plus you get their email.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the application and how customised you want it to be, but you probably want to use a 3d library like three.js, babylon, etc.

If you just want to view and rotate 3d models without too much programming then you might want to use something like [modelviewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) or [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/)